# Is there any way to know which Class instance , NSData Object contains?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I have an NSData object which I obtained from a web server.

the contents of this data object are supposed to be a UIImage . but when i used it in the following code :-

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData * responseData, NSError *err) {

    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Err %@",err.description);

    }else
    {

        if (responseData) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Data Length %d  ",[responseData length]);
            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:responseData];

            if (img) {
                NSLog(@"image in not null");
                self.imageView.image = img;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"image is null");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"not returning anything");
        }
    }
}];
```

the out put says :-

```
Data Length 2786779
image is null
```

so i guess its not an Image

is there a way from which i could get to know which class instance does this NSData contains

PS:-
I also used

```
NSLog("Description %@",data.description);
```

but it only generated a huge sequence of hex codes

Comment: isKindofClass did u try that?

Comment: the image data from the remote server may be Base64 encoded, which you can decode.

Comment: From the docs :

"A new image object for the specified data, or nil if the method could not initialize the image from the specified data.
"
Your data is not recognized as an image, maybe a backend issue ?

Comment: Are you sure your url is an image url? You can try to download a simple image like the google image and verify: https://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo11w.png.

Comment: @OMerObaid : well... isn't that gonna return me NSData ?? because its an NSData object

Comment: You can check the answer to this question :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6539592/2790086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well....
it might be possible that your server is sending an image but its encoded.

getting your UIImage *img = null doesn't necessarily mean that the response data is not an Image. if you aren't decoding it back, it will be null of course

I think your response data is encoded in Base64...(most servers do)

if so,...

first download .h and .m files from this [Link](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64)

add and import them in your project.

then use this code

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:str];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

this img will have your image. if your server is really sending an image.

please note that.. not all of NSString *str in this code is representation of a UIImage
it might be some part of it. and the rest can be information related to this image.
so you have to decode only the image part of the response.

hope this helps....

Comment: Wow...
this was exactly i needed . . you are a savior..:)

Comment: @DemonSOCKET Given, the server sends an image for example as `image/png` it makes absolutely no sense the server base64 decodes it. It would make sense for example, if the response were JSON, and the image would be embedded into a JSON string - which must be characters (not binary). So, it seems you are receiving the image in a quite suboptimal way. I would check that.

Comment: @An_ISOL'iean It's not true that "most" servers will base64 encode images. In fact, this is not needed. Servers will send an image according their "Content-Type". This can be for example `image/png` - and this allows the server to send the image as _binary_ in PNG, unless something is bogus in the server.

Answer (score 1):

A `NSData` object contains a sequence of bytes, not objects (e.g. UIImages). It can be a representation of an image, though.

You should check the "Content-Type" header of the response. It is a MIME type which specifies the kind of data in the response body (see also wiki [Internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)).

You can obtain the MIME type as a NSString from the `NSURLResponse`as follows:

```
NSString* mimeType = [response MIMEType];
```

(see also [NSURLResponse Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLResponse/MIMEType))

A MIME type is composed of a *type* and a *subtype*, and may contain "parameters".

For example, `text/plain; charset=utf-8` is a media type whose "type" is "text" and whose "subtype" is "plain". It has one parameter specifying the character encoding of the byte sequence, which is in this case, Unicode UTF-8.

In your example, you would expect a MIME type whose "type" equals "image", for example:

`image/gif`,  `image/jpeg`, `image/png`, etc.

Comment: well.. i have checked as you suggested and the mimeType was "text/plain". actually the answer of @An_ISOL'iean did the trick. but i am not pretty much sure what exactly is happening over here. could you please help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is not data of a image.
Use below code to log data as NSString and see result.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```